# ActiveRecord Prepared Statement Invalid in Oracle

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, activerecord

As you can see Ruby dont escape ***:MI*** so I am catching some nasty errors.
I am stuck in the middle of migrating to Oracle11g from MySQL and I can't refactor code, have to make it rough. I promise I'll rewrite code!
Here is part of my code

```
.joins("LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM days ) days ON SYSDATE = to_date(to_char(days.date_x, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') ")
     .where("attach_offices.ab_id = :abs_id AND
            to_date(to_char(to_date('#{@date}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24\:MI\:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') between to_date(to_char(attach_offices.dt_begin, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date(to_char(attach_offices.dt_end, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND

              users.is_admin = 0",
              {:abs_id => current_user.ab_id, :current_user_id => current_user.id})
```

And teh error:

```
missing value for :MI in attach_offices.ab_id = :abs_id AND 
        to_date(to_char(to_date('2014-02-26 12:13:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') between to_date(to_char(attach_offices.dt_begin, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date(to_char(attach_offices.dt_end, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND

          users.is_admin = 0
```

I tried #{%q(HH24:MI:SS)} and it didnt help. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the purpose of `to_date(to_char(to_date('#{@date}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24\:MI\:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')`? If getting rid of time part then you could simply truncate the date: `TRUNC(to_date('#{@date}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24\:MI\:SS'))`. Seems that Ruby thinks `:MI` is bind variable.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin thank you for the idea of date truncation, but still ruby ignore escape char. I checked for the quotes, brackets, etc., all seems right.

Comment: Still the best way to overwhelm this problem is to edit the original @date with `@date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`, so I can use `TRUNC(to_date('#{@date}', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))`